# Awesomium WebControl glitches and disappears from windows during Design

Tags: visual-studio-2013, awesomium

I have a solution, with a vb project and a window with some controls and a WebControl. I resized the window, saved, et voilà: the WebControl disappeared. I closed and restarted VS and it seems to be gone forever...

Comment: same here and I was trying to delete Awesomium in favor of webkitdotnet it must of knew I was trying to delete it ;)

Comment: Is webkitdotnet better, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the form designer file and remove all lines containing the webcontrol. This deletes the webcontrol so you can add a new one. Then name the new webcontrol with the same name as the old and everything should work fine

Comment: Thanks, I will check if this works next time I use Awesomium

Comment: Problem with this is that you will have to go back through your entire code and remember everywhere you put the webcontrol code in. What I do is just add another webcontrol which will be named webcontrol2. Then I go through and replace all the 'webcontrol1' with 'webcontrol2'. I hope they fix this glitch.